# Where is shared library loaded into by the operating system?

Tags: operating-system, shared-libraries

Is it true that shared library is loaded into the stack of the calling process by the operating system?

Comment: No...................

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that shared library is loaded into the stack of the calling process by the operating system?

No.

They are loaded into the *virtual memory* of the process (but not the *stack*), and precise details differ between different OSes.